# What is Source Compatibility in Java?

Tags: java, compilation, jvm, bytecode

I am reading [Kinds of Compatibility](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/csr/Kinds+of+Compatibility) but I am not able to understand it. Can someone explain it a little please ?

From whatever I was able to grasp, it seems that source compatibility implies that a code written in X should be able to be compile in X+1.

However, further details about how method resolution works seem to add further more details to it giving impression that there is more to source compatibility than just being able to compile in later versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being able to compile with X+1 is the simplest form of source compatibility.

The article you link to defines 3 levels of source compatibility (4 if you count "not source compatible"):

1. it still compiles
2. it still compiles and behaves the same way as in version X
3. it still compiles and it compiles into effectively the same binary (binary-preserving)

#1 is obvious.

#2 can be broken because if your library version X had a method `foo(Object)` and your source had a line that read `yourObject.foo("someString")` then if X+1 added a method `foo(String)` then compiling against X+1 would bind that method to the new method and not the old one.

If calling `foo(Object)` with `"someString"` has the same effect as calling `foo(String)` with `"someString"` then #2 would still apply, because they produce identical behaviour.

#3 is about that specific difference: if your source would now call another method, then this level is broken. That can matter if you want to compile against a newer library and still run against an older version (as is often the case for Android).

Comment: Can you please add a few more pointers for #3 ?

Answer (score 2):

In general:

Source Compatibility - Will this source file compile in the current environment (required dependencies present, etc).

Binary Compatibility - Will this compiled bytecode run successfully in the current environment (dependency classes/methods exist, etc).

Behavioral Compatibility - Will this compiled bytecode behave properly in the current environment (same input leads to same output in dependencies)

Java seeks to maintain backward compatibility between source code and compiled bytecode. This means that a program written and compiled in Java 6 should run seamlessly in Java 8. The way the Java language is designed, not all classes are 'executables'. Some may be utility classes with functions useful in a variety of applications.

These dependencies can be imported in the executable module using import a.* if the utility class is a.MyUtility. However, if the import regex matches 2 classes with the same name (ex: there is also an import b.* and a b.MyUtility class), it will not be possible to resolve which MyUtility class to use on execution.